# application closed on http post process

Tags: java, android

aim trying process http post for user login information by remote server

my code works good on 2.3.3 but on 4.1 and 4.2 the application is force closed

my AndroidManifest.xml file has

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
    android:maxSdkVersion="17" />
```

and the code aim using for http post process is

```
public class postdata  { 
public static final String Logger = postdata.class.getName();
private static String slurp(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
       byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        for (int n; (n = in.read(b)) != -1;) {
          out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
       }
     return out.toString();
 }
public static String post_string(String url, String urlParameters) throws IOException {
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
   try {
     conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   Log.e(Logger, "MalformedURLException While Creating URL Connection - " + e.getMessage());
   throw e;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Creating URL Connection - " + e.getMessage());
    throw e;
 }
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(urlParameters.length()));
  OutputStream os = null; 
  try {
      os = conn.getOutputStream();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Creating URL OutputStream - " + e.getMessage());
     throw e;
  } 
  try { 
       os.write(urlParameters.toString().getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
  Log.e(Logger, "IOException While writting URL OutputStream - " + e.getMessage());
  throw e; 
   }
  InputStream in = null; 
   try {
      in = conn.getInputStream();
   } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Creating URL InputStream - " + e.getMessage());
     throw e;
   }
    String output = null;
    try {
        output = slurp(in);
    } catch (IOException e) { 
      Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Reading URL OutputStream - " + e.getMessage());
      throw e;
    } finally {
     try {
      os.close();
      in.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Closing URL Output and Input Stream - " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
 conn.disconnect();return output;
}
}
```

how to make my code work on all android versions without problem ?

Comment: Please, post the LogCat report

Comment: aim still a beginner how to get the logCat ?

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to perform Network operations on UI thread, please move your Network related operations to a background Thread, preferably an AsyncTask, [see this example on how to do it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/892055).

Comment: my code work will on android 2.3.3 but on android 4.1 or 4.2 its auto closed not working when i try to http post any data

Comment: Yes it will fail on 4.1 and up devices as Strict mode is enabled by default, please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: ok got it thank you , but is there any ready function or class i can use ? aim still a beginner so its look difficult for me

Comment: See the link given in the answer ...

Comment: see this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/8464859/892055

Comment: so lovely its worked with AsyncTask :D Finally i did it thanks guys

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted, as will help other people identify the solution.